# Cross section of a cable

Tags: power-supply, cables

The table below, gives some parameters of DC cables:

[image]

Based on the table above, the average diameter of the first cable (1x2.50) is 5.1 mm.

As far as i know the cross section can be found by the following equation.
S = pi* r^2 , where r is the radius of cable.

However, if you do the math, the calculated cross section is 20,417 mm^2  which is significantly different from the section of the table (6 mm^2).

Where am I wrong ?

Comment: Is this stranded wire?

Comment: @user253751 its Flexible tinned copper

Comment: Does flexible mean stranded? Also, is there more than one wire in the cable?

Comment: @user253751 In order to have access to all the specifications, the cable is the : H1Z2Z2-K Solar cables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that the first row of the table refers to a stranded wire where the total cross-sectional area of the conductor (i.e., "Nominal section") equals 2.5 mm<sup>2</sup> (roughly AWG13). It is made up of 50 strands of 0.25 mm diameter wire (about AWG30).

The diameter of a solid 2.5 mm<sup>2</sup> wire would be 1.78 mm. A stranded wire is somewhat larger, around 2.0 mm (roughly 8 layers of the 0.25 mm wire). This conductive core is surrounded by 0.75 mm of "insulation" and 0.80 mm of "sheath", for a total diameter of 5.1 mm for the wire plus all of its coatings.